# Normal distribution -- predicting weight using conditional probability

Tags: self-study, distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

The weight in pounds of people in a certain population has a normal distribution, with a mean of 150 and standard deviation of 40. 
Of the people who weigh over 170 lbs, what percent weigh more than 200?
(using conditional probability)

To do this, I calculated the probability P(x>170) ==> .3085 (using normal distribution)
Using the conditional probability formula 
P( x>200 | x>170) = P( x>200 AND x>170) / P(x>170)

*Here it seems like P(x>200 and x>170) is equal to P(x>200) -- is this wrong to assume?

I'm not sure how to come up with P(x>200 and x>170) -- sticking to formulas, are these events dependent?

Any insights are greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(x>200 and x>170) = P(x>200) .

I wouldn't call it an assumption. I'd call it a fact.  Any x which is > 200 is necessarily greater than 170. I.e., In the event "x>200 and x>170",  "and x > 170" is redundant.

Comment: Thank you! This is obvious, not sure why I was confused by it:) Thanks for your help